# Visual Studio 2010 Pro - SuppressMessage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, suppress-warnings

Is the option to SupressMessage not available in VS 2010 Pro?

When I right click on the warning in the warning list there is no option to suppress. I also tried it with errors and there was no option. I then tried to create my own GlobalSuppression.cs file but have no idea what category the warning should be classified under.

Right now I'm doing this, which works, but I would prefer to use a GlobalSuppression file

```
#pragma warning disable 0649,0169
[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
private IModuleManager _moduleManager;

[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
private IRegionManager _regionManager;

[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
private IRibbonService _menuService;
#pragma warning restore 0649,0169
```

These are the warnings from the output window that I want to suppress:

```
warning CS0649: Field 'Shell._moduleManager' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
warning CS0169: The field 'Shell._regionManager' is never used
warning CS0649: Field 'Shell._menuService' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

The reason why I want to suppress is that my solution uses Prism / MEF so those variables are assigned at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSxxxx warnings you are seeing are C# compiler warnings, not FxCop/Code Analysis warnings.  They must be suppressed using `#pragma warning disable` directives, not SuppressMessage attributes.

Incidentally, integrated Code Analysis is only availabe in Premium or Ultimate, not Pro.