# How can I supress Intellisense warnings such as "variable is never assigned to.."?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, warnings, intellisense

I'm playing around with MEF. Problem is, Visual Studio ('12, Pro) thinks that my imported stuff is never assigned to and helpfully highlights a warning:

[image: Screenshot of code with a VS warning.]

I know it's only cosmetic, but (since these warnings are usually worth heeding) I find it distracting.

In my research I've found two methods which allege to suppress the warning, but they seem to be referring to warnings at build time, rather than from Intellisense:

- [The `SupressMethod` attribute](http://www.chris-alexander.co.uk/5328)
- [The `#pragma warning disable` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004832/visual-studio-2010-pro-suppressmessage)

Is there a way to suppress the IntelliSense warnings?

Answer (score -3):

Just make it a public property, and you won't get the warning in the first place.

Comment: Or protected (may be even field) if you don't want to share it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither of these suggestions help. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong? Could you add a code sample?